# user input of the students grades into an output as a text box then compute the final letter grade

Tags: javascript, function

I need to make the JS code I've gotten so far output to a text box (that's read-only) instead of displayed on the page after clicking the GPA submit button.

I also need help figuring out how to take the GPA that is calculated and outputted to that text box rounded up to the nearest whole number and pasted into a grade letter format instead of a number.

Something like:
*"you got a 97 percent, which means you get an A"*
    or
*"you got an 80 percent which means you get a B"*

Here are the percent equivalents broken down:

```
90-100 A
80-89  B
70-79  C
60-69  D
0-59   F
```

*If the student's final grade is 'D' or 'F' the text should read something like "Student has failed and must retake the course"

```html
<h1>Student Grades</h1>
<h2>Please Enter Your Percentage For Course Section</h2>
<label>Homework</label>
<input type="number" id="hmwk" size=2 value="hmwk">
<br>
<label>Midterm</label>
<input type="number" id="mdtm" size=2 value="mdtm">
<br>
<label>Final</label>
<input type="number" id="final" size=2 value="final">
<br>
<label>Part</label>
<input type="number" id="prtc" size=2 value="prtc">
<br>
<input type="button" value="GPA" onclick="grade()">
<div id="outputDiv" style="height: 50px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function grade() {
    var grd1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('hmwk').value * 0.5);
    var grd2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('mdtm').value * 0.2);
    var grd3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('final').value * 0.2);
    var grd4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('prtc').value * 0.1);
    var total = grd1 + grd2 + grd3 + grd4;
    var display = document.getElementById('outputDiv');
    display.innerHTML = 'Your Final Grade Is: ' + total;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Calculating the percentage out of `total` should be straightforward, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind to use `switch` statements, this should do the trick :

```html
<h1>Student Grades</h1>
<h2>Please Enter Your Percentage For Course Section</h2>
<label>Homework</label>
<input type="number" id="hmwk" size=2 value="hmwk">
<br>
<label>Midterm</label>
<input type="number" id="mdtm" size=2 value="mdtm">
<br>
<label>Final</label>
<input type="number" id="final" size=2 value="final">
<br>
<label>Part</label>
<input type="number" id="prtc" size=2 value="prtc">
<br>
<input type="button" value="GPA" onclick="grade()">
<div id="outputDiv" style="height: 50px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function grade() {
var grd1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('hmwk').value * 0.5);
var grd2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('mdtm').value * 0.2);
var grd3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('final').value * 0.2);
var grd4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('prtc').value * 0.1);
var total = grd1 + grd2 + grd3 + grd4;
var display = document.getElementById('outputDiv');
let msg = '';
let grade = 0;
switch (true) {
    case (total >= 90 && total <= 100):
        grade = "A";
        break;
    case (total >= 80 && total <= 89):
        grade = "B";
        break;
    case (total >= 70 && total <= 79):
        grade = "C";
        break;
    case (total >= 60 && total <= 69):
        grade = "D";
        break;
    case (total >= 0 && total <= 59):
        grade = "F";
        break;
    default:
        grade = "F";
        break;
}
msg = "you got a " + total + " percent, which means you get an " + grade;
display.innerHTML = 'Your Final Grade Is: ' + total + "<br/>" + msg;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This is probably the better answer even though we haven't done switch statements yet... since it's complete and you showed me how to add it to my code. which is 50% of the reason JS is so hard for me. So thank you. But this still doesn't output to a text box, just outputs on the screen like I had it :/ and i cannot figure out for the life of me how to simply change my output which is currently just diplaying below the button, to instead display in a text box (which I'll make read only). It seems so simple but i don't really understand how to mix JS with html quite that well.

Comment: you're welcome.. :) , do you mean inside a textbox like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/pch2tmqd/)?

Comment: ugh YES!! you're a genius. Thank you so much for helping me, I've been so overwhelmed :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var gradePercentageOriginal; //percentage of grade

var gradePercentage = Math.ceil(gradePercentage);

var letterGrade;

if (gradePercentage <= 90) {
   letterGrade = "A";
}else if (89 <= gradePercentage && gradePercentage <= 80) {
   letterGrade = "B";
}else if (79 <= gradePercentage && gradePercentage <= 70) {
   letterGrade = "C";
}else if (69 <= gradePercentage && gradePercentage <= 60) {
   letterGrade = "D";
}else {
   letterGrade = "F";
}

display.innerHTML = 'Your Final Grade Is: ' + letterGrade;

</script>
```

You could also create a `switch` statement:

```
switch(true) {
 case(gradePercentage <= 90):
   letterGrade = "A";
   break;
  .
  .
  .
 case(gradePercentage <= 69 && gradePercentage => 60):
   letterGrade = "D";
   break;
 default:
   letterGrade = "F";
   break;
}
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Wow! Thank you! This has greatly helped me!!

Comment: although i might add that trying to figure out where to add this with my original code was something i failed on... :( Also this still doesn't output to a text box, just outputs on the screen like I had it :/

Comment: after trying to make this mesh with my current code for the past three hours... i am more confused. lol I like the first simpler response bc I actually understand that one better... but you used variables I didn't declare in my original code and you didn't tell me how to combine that with the function I already have. unfortunately i'm at a VERY BASIC learning level here lol

Comment: That is okay, we all have to start somewhere. Just read up online, I recommend W3 schools. Sorry if I left you confused.

Comment: I appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<h1>Student Grades</h1>
<h2>Please Enter Your Percentage For Course Section</h2>
<label>Homework</label>
<input type="number" id="hmwk" size=2 value="hmwk">
<br>
<label>Midterm</label>
<input type="number" id="mdtm" size=2 value="mdtm">
<br>
<label>Final</label>
<input type="number" id="final" size=2 value="final">
<br>
<label>Part</label>
<input type="number" id="prtc" size=2 value="prtc">
<br>
<input type="button" value="GPA" onclick="grade()">
<div id="outputDiv" style="height: 50px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function grade() {
var grd1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('hmwk').value * 0.5);
var grd2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('mdtm').value * 0.2);
var grd3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('final').value * 0.2);
var grd4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('prtc').value * 0.1);
var total = grd1 + grd2 + grd3 + grd4;
var display = document.getElementById('outputDiv');
let msg = '';
let grade = 0;
switch (true) {
    case (total >= 90 && total <= 100):
        grade = "A";
        break;
    case (total >= 80 && total <= 89):
        grade = "B";
        break;
    case (total >= 70 && total <= 79):
        grade = "C";
        break;
    case (total >= 60 && total <= 69):
        grade = "D";
        break;
    case (total >= 0 && total <= 59):
        grade = "F";
        break;
    default:
        grade = "F";
        break;
}
msg = "you got a " + total + " percent, which means you get an " + grade;
display.innerHTML = 'Your Final Grade Is: ' + total + "<br/>" + msg;
  }
</script>
```